# how does thread management work in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

As part of a project, I need to manage the number of threads used by a CNN written in tensorflow and thus avoid parallelization. After reading the documentation, I'm having trouble understanding exactly how this works.

I've already limited the number of threads by directly limiting the program with "taskset", but I have the impression that I'm getting confused. Could someone clarify this for me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

> I need to manage the number of threads used by a CNN written in
> tensorflow and thus avoid parallelization

If you wish to manage the level of parallelization in a Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) using TensorFlow and specifically control the number of threads employed, you can adjust the environment variable `TF_NUM_INTRAOP_THREADS`. This variable dictates the quantity of threads allocated for intra-operation parallelism, dealing with parallel execution within a single operation (such as matrix multiplication).

> I've already limited the number of threads by directly limiting the
> program with "taskset", but I have the impression that I'm getting
> confused.

If you have already constrained the number of threads using "taskset" and are still encountering confusion or issues, it's possible that additional factors may be influencing the thread behavior.

TensorFlow offers a range of environment variables that allow users to fine-tune its behavior. In addition to TF_NUM_INTRAOP_THREADS,you can explore some other variables such as [TF_NUM_INTEROP_THREADS](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/threading/set_inter_op_parallelism_threads) and OMP_NUM_THREADS, which influences the OpenMP threads utilized by TensorFlow. Modifying these parameters can provide additional control over the parallelism characteristics.